# Why does \noindent not work properly here?

Tags: indentation

I defined a new environment, similar (but not equal) to `listings`:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{lines}
{\par\begingroup\nobreak
\vspace{3pt}\parindent0pt\hrule\kern5pt
\nobreak\obeylines\everypar{\strut}\endgroup}
{\par\begingroup\nobreak
\vspace{3pt}\parindent0pt\hrule\kern5pt
\nobreak\obeylines\everypar{\strut}\endgroup%
\noindent%
}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{lines}
Some nifty code and stuffz
\end{lines}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Why does my `\noindent` keep a small space before the text? Did I miss something?

Comment: Add `\ignorespacesafterend` after `\noindent`.

Comment: Thanks. Why doesn't it align automatically?

Comment: It does align but you added a space at the start of the line, so TeX typeset it. (ends of lines are word spaces in TeX)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `\noindent` you will almost always get this behaviour. The space is an inter word space being typeset from the end of line after the environment.

You can avoid the problem by using `\ignorespacesafterend` but that is papering over the cracks. The error is using `\noindent` which has started horizontal mode prematurely which is why the end of line is typeset as a space. LaTeX environments never do this. You should define the environment using `trivlist` then the environment will end in vertical mode, but if no blank line follows indentation will be suppressed (it is actually removed using `\lastbox` rather than not being added using `\noindent`.)

Something like this, adjust lengths to suit.

[image]

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{linez}
 {\trivlist\nopagebreak
  \parindent0pt
  \vspace{3pt}%
  \hrule
  \vspace{-3pt}%
  \item\relax\obeylines}
 {\par
  \nopagebreak
  \vspace{3pt}%
  \hrule
  \vspace{3pt}%
  \endtrivlist}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{linez}
Some nifty code and stuffz
Some nifty code and stuffz
Some nifty code and stuffz
Some nifty code and stuffz
\end{linez}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I've used `trivlist` and it also changed the indentation of items inside the environment. What is the most versatile solution to getting this whitespace back? `\indent` appears pretty crippled at the moment.

Comment: @1010011010 see update

Answer (score 5):

You're missing `\ignorespacesafterend`, but the definition doesn't do `\obeylines`, because you're enclosing it in a group and its effect disappears at `\endgroup`:

```
\documentclass{ltxdoc}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newenvironment{linez}
 {\par\nopagebreak
  \vspace{3pt}
  \parindent0pt
  \hrule\kern5pt
  \obeylines}
 {\par
  \nopagebreak
  \vspace{3pt}
  \hrule\kern5pt
  \noindent\ignorespacesafterend}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{linez}
Some nifty code and stuffz
Some nifty code and stuffz
Some nifty code and stuffz
Some nifty code and stuffz
\end{linez}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

[image]